# Copy AWS Simple Email Service Files to an S3 Bucket in Another Account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

**Here's the question:**

Is there a way to use `aws s3 sync...` to take files  delivered by SES into an S3 bucket in one account and copy them into an S3 bucket in another account?

**Details:**

I setup an [Amazon Simple Email Service (SES)](https://aws.amazon.com/ses/) address that drops emails into an S3 bucket. I'm trying to use the aws cli command `aws s3 sync` to copy the files into a bucket in another account for testing.

I setup both accounts per the AWS "[How can I copy S3 objects from another AWS account](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/copy-s3-objects-account/)" support article, but it's not working for files delivered by SES. When I run the command, all SES files fail with:

> download failed: {SOURCE} to {DESTINATION} An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the GetObject operation: Access Denied

That's only for the files delivered by SES though. Any files that I drop in directly transfer just fine.

Based off [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/927364/access-denied-for-some-files-when-syncing-buckets), I started looking at the owner of the objects and discovered that the SES delivered files have an owner of `aws-ses+publishing.us-east-1.prod`. But, it looks like the actual account should have full access. Specifically, when I run:

```
aws s3api get-object-acl --bucket {MY_BUCKET} --key {MY_KEY}
```

it returns:

```json
{
  "Owner": {
    "DisplayName": "my_display_name",
    "ID": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  },
  "Grants": [{
    "Grantee": {
      "DisplayName": "my_display_name",
      "ID": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "Type": "CanonicalUser"
    },
    "Permission": "FULL_CONTROL"
  }]
}
```

And, when I run it on a file delivered by SES, I get:

```json
{
  "Owner": {
    "DisplayName": "aws-ses+publishing.us-east-1.prod",
    "ID": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  },
  "Grants": [
    {
      "Grantee": {
        "DisplayName": "aws-ses+publishing.us-east-1.prod",
        "ID": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "Type": "CanonicalUser"
      },
      "Permission": "FULL_CONTROL"
    },
    {
      "Grantee": {
        "DisplayName": "my_display_name",
        "ID": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "Type": "CanonicalUser"
      },
      "Permission": "FULL_CONTROL"
    }
  ]
}
```

Given the grant statements for my account, it seems like it should work.

I found [this thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=171193) on the AWS forum that discusses how to change ownership of a key. It says you can't directly, but you can copy the key back onto itself with:

```
aws s3 cp s3://mybucket/mykey s3://mybucket/mykey --storage-class STANDARD
```

Doing so updates the owner of the object. I tried that with an SES delivered file and sure enough, after getting the owner update, I could transfer it with `aws s3 sync...`.

So, that works, but it seems like a hack. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: I'm afraid that's the way to go. Maybe you can create a lambda which will handle this for you + maybe setup cross-region bucket replication if everything needs to be synced.

Comment: The owner of the file remains ses but it gives bucket owner full control and to copy it to different account, you need to recopy the object to the same bucket so you can become owner and s3 sync can work. Pretty much this is the solution and you already using it, however you could write a lambda function for PUT event in S3 bucket and buffer the file from bucket and write it to other bucket pragmatically to avoid doing it manually.